# Sorting Array in array variable

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
$data = array(
    array(
    'name'=>'guguk',
    'nilai'=>3
    ),
    array(
    'name'=>'gogok',
    'nilai'=>7
    )
);
```

so, how should I do to sort array base on attribute 'nilai'?

Comment: Search for "php multidimensional sorting by value"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

**Try this**

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["nilai"] - $b["nilai"];
}
usort($data, "cmp");
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create code like

```
    array_multisort($ar1, $ar2);
```

refrence link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php